# Spring 3: Autowire a bean declared in xml application context to a @Component bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I am having an issue with autowiring a bean property in my class declared as a `@Component`. I've tried a number of different things, but unfortunately I am getting a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` during spring configuration for this particular bean.

Below is a some example code, to model what I have currently.

```
package com.foo.bar;

@Component
public class MyDeployer implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    @Autowired
    private ClusterRegistry clusterRegistry; //The bean I am trying to wire

    ...
}
```

In my application context, I have the following:

```
<beans ...... />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.foo.bar" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="clusterRegistry" name="clusterRegistry" class="com.my.implementation.ClusterRegistryFileImpl" />
</beans>
```

My ClusterRegistryFileImpl class is defined below:

```
package com.my.implementation;

public final class ClusterRegistryFileImpl implements ClusterRegistry
{
    ...
}
```

Note that the ClusterRegistryFileImpl implements the ClusterRegistry interface, and this interface/implementation class has no dependencies. These files also are not using component scan (and are not annotated by `@Component`, but I wouldn't think they'd need to be if I'm declaring the bean in my appContext.

My integration test looks like

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {
    "/com/app/context/path/appContext.xml",
    "/com/app/context/path/aDifferentAppContext.xml"
})
public class MyDeployerTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private MyDeployer deployer; //class that uses the bean I need

    @Test
    protected void testDeployerStartup()
    {
        deployer.startup();
        ...
    }

}
```

Below is the error:

```
Caused by: 
  org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
  No qualifying bean of type [com.my.implementation.ClusterRegistry] found for dependency: 
  expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Any suggestions or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks ok for me. Any chance you could show the implementing class?

Comment: Sure, although I'm not sure how helpful it would be. The implementation class is in the same package as its interface.

Comment: Is your app a desktop one or web?

Comment: Hm, final class. Any aspects involved?

Comment: My application is a web application. There are no aspects involved in this code. Thanks for taking a look guys.

Comment: Also, not sure if it matters, but I am importing my application context into my integration test using the following:

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/com/my/app/context/appContext.xml"})

Comment: Is the error only showing up in your integration tests?

Comment: Could you also post the code for the test that is failing? Does Spring not complain when you run the application in a regular environment?

Comment: I have not ran the application in a regular environment (my project is part of a much larger framework). I ended up finding a bit of a workaround, which is, sticking the bean declaration in another application-context that I was importing into my integration test (Using the @ContextConfiguration spring annotation).

I'll post some example test code.

Answer (score 0):

Your class
    ClusterRegistryFileImpl
should has an annotation ( like @Service if is a service class, or @Repository or @Component).

And i am not sure if the final accessor applies.

Comment: I did try this (along with adding the package which the Interface/Implementation classes live in into the basepackage attribute in the component-scan declaration). No luck, unfortunately.